# How to encrypt a secondary drive with a keyfile and auto-mount without root password

Tags: mount, encryption, luks, veracrypt

I have a ssd as boot drive and want to encrypt a secondary hdd and automatically mount the drive at user login. And very important, I only want to enter my password once.

I tried luks and veracrypt. The problem with luks is that I need either to enter the encryption key manually or store the keyfile on an insecure location. The problem with veracrypt is that I need to enter my root password for mounting after login or give veracrypt root permissions which can be dangerous.

I'd be very grateful if anyone had a solution for that.